# Decimal separator for real numbers in textfiles XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

The following code gives a real number for Writeln(Outfile,testreal) with a '.' decimal separator even though I have ',' defined in my Windows system. How can I write a number to a text file using Writeln(Outfile,testreal)?

(The FloatToStr method gives ok result as it should.)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Outfile:textfile;
    testreal:single;
    StrDummy : string;

begin
  testreal:=1234.1234;
  assignfile(Outfile,'test_real.txt');
  Rewrite(Outfile);
  StrDummy:='Decimal Separator in Windows: '+GetLocaleChar(GetThreadLocale, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, '.')+#13#10+
            'Decimal Separator in Delphi:  '+DecimalSeparator;
  Writeln(Outfile,StrDummy);
  Writeln(Outfile,testreal);
  Writeln(Outfile,FloatToStr(testreal));
  Closefile(Outfile);
end;
```

gives

```
Decimal Separator in Windows: ,
Decimal Separator in Delphi:  ,
 1.23412341308594E+0003                      //Ps. Why is there a beginning space here? 
1234,12341308594
```

Comment: Be careful if you need to read the text file back in. A valid real number may not be interpreted correctly in a different local with a different decimal separator.

Comment: The space is reserved for a sign. Depending on the type of text file you are storing, you may want to store decimal values in a standardised way independent of locale. That way the values can be read back in any locale.

Comment: If you are writing floating point values into XML documents, standard decimal char is a `.`. `TXMLDocument` in Delphi may not respect that fact, see [`Writing decimal value to the XML`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=78425).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Legacy Pascal I/O uses `Str` to convert floating point values to text. And `Str` hard codes a decimal separator of `.`.

I suggest you use a more modern form of I/O. For example the `TStreamWriter` class which uses `FloatToStr` to convert floating point to text.

Comment: It is due to a conversion of an old Delphi 2007 project with many lines of code using the old I/O style. Is there no way to set the Str decimal property?

Comment: You'd have to hack the code. It's hard coded. Personally I'd be surprised if Delphi 2007 was any different. It's hard-coded as `'.'` in Delphi 6 which is the legacy Delphi that I have at hand. So your problem existed even before the port to modern Delphi.

Comment: @Thomas - No, there is no way to do it. I put aside the idea of editing System.pas and rebuilding RTL.

Comment: @David ...which may broke some Legacy code. I believe using dot is documented for Str, Val, Read(text) and Write(text) since Turbo Pascal and i saw code explicitly using Str/Val to get always the same string value no matter what DecimalSeparator set to be.

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm certainly not advocating hacking the code. Ditching Pascal I/O is the answer.

Comment: @David Ps. You were absolutely right that Delphi 2007 works in the same way. I was wrong here (I see now I used a quick solution just replacing '.' with ',' in the written text file afterwards...).